# Using DevexpressGridview BeforeGetCallbackResult

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

Im using a devexpress gridview and want to trigger a javascript from "gridviewsettings.BeforeGetCallbackResult " However i don't find how to do this.

Should be simple enough but im missing something!

```
settings.BeforeGetCallbackResult = (s, e) =>
{
           //Run js function: getStatusMessages() here!
};
```

Anny ideas?

Edit 1;

Found solution
settings.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "getStatusMessages";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something i obviously missed;

Solution: settings.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "getStatusMessages";